# windows 2003 standard freezes at boot

Tags: windows-server-2003, boot

I got myself today a windows 2003 standard which refuses to boot

the system is installed on a hardware raid (if it makes any difference)

when booting in safe mode, I have the following files loaded (all in /system32)

- ntoskrnl.dll
- hal.dll
- kdcom.dll
- bootvid.dll
- /config/system

at which it freezes and does nothing

not having a bootable cd with me (neither linux, nor the win 2k3) I have tried to boot "last good configuration" which did not work either

having searched on the internet for possible solutions, I came into using the rescue console and repairing the system; though it did not work all the times, seems to be the favourite solutions

I would like to recover the system without reinstalling (there is important data on it, along with a few programs installed which I don;t have the original cd's)

thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if the hardware RAID is reporting any errors. (During boot, there's usually a prompt to hit control-M or similar to enter the RAID configuration menu.)

Since safe mode didn't work, you might try reinstalling - choose the same folder Windows is already installed in. You should be prompted to repair that installation. If and when you are, go for it. I've used that technique successfully a number of times. (Wish I hadn't needed to.)

If successful, you'll need to re-update the server via Windows Update, etc.

Comment: before booting, there is a raid screen where says something about "healthy"; on several threads on the need I noticed a possible cause for this error could be a bad hdd in the array
the ugly part is that not knowing what to backup, I'll have to move a few hundred gb over the network :(